# Passing table name inside proc to store its row count into a variable

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I want to write a simple pl/sql procedure which will take a table name as input and it will store the table row count into a variable . I have written the bellow code :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure ATT_REP.proc_compare2(table_name IN varchar2)
is
cnt NUMBER(30);
begin
       execute immediate 'select count(*) from '||table_name||' into '||cnt ;
     dbms_output.put_line(cnt);
end;
/
```

while executing i am getting 'PLS-00357: Table,View Or Sequence reference 'CES_ODS.ENTITY' not allowed in this context' error.
Please suggest what am i doing wrong . How can i make it working .

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ATT_REP.proc_compare2 (table_name IN VARCHAR2)
IS
   cnt        NUMBER (30);
   sql_stmt   VARCHAR2 (200);
BEGIN
   sql_stmt := 'select count(*) from ' || table_name;

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt INTO cnt;

   DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (cnt);
END;
/
```